SIM900 won't send message (+CME ERROR: invalid input value)
Last night code was working, but when I tried today I got +CME ERROR: invalid input value.
I'm using arduino uno and sim900.
Code I used is from randomnerdtutorials.
`/*********
  Complete project details at https://randomnerdtutorials.com  
*********/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Configure software serial port
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8); 

void setup() {

  SIM900.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Send the SMS
  sendSMS();
}

void loop() { 
  
}

void sendSMS() {
  Serial.println("Sending SMS");
  // AT command to set SIM900 to SMS mode
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
  delay(100);

  SIM900.println("AT+CMGS=\"+381601xxxxxx\""); 
  delay(100);
  
  SIM900.println("Hello"); 
  delay(100);

// End AT command with a ^Z, ASCII code 26
  SIM900.println((char)26); 
  delay(100);
  SIM900.println();
  // Give module time to send SMS
  long int time = millis();
  while ((time + 10000) > millis()) {
    while (SIM900.available()) {
      String response = SIM900.readString();
      Serial.println(response); 
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Sent");
}`

15:41:20.146 -> Sending command: AT
15:41:22.181 -> Response: 
15:41:22.181 -> OK
15:41:22.181 -> 
15:41:22.181 -> Sending command: AT+CPIN?
15:41:24.156 -> Response: 
15:41:24.188 -> +CPIN: READY
15:41:24.188 -> 
15:41:24.188 -> OK
15:41:24.188 -> 
15:41:24.188 -> Sending command: AT+CSQ
15:41:26.163 -> Response: 
15:41:26.195 -> +CSQ: 25,0
15:41:26.195 -> 
15:41:26.195 -> OK
15:41:26.195 -> 
15:41:26.195 -> Sending command: AT+CREG?
15:41:28.170 -> Response: 
15:41:28.202 -> +CREG: 0,1
15:41:28.202 -> 
15:41:28.202 -> OK
15:41:28.202 -> 
15:41:28.202 -> Sending command: AT+CSCA?
15:41:30.210 -> Response: 
15:41:30.210 -> +CSCA: "002B00330038003100360033003100300030003100300030",145
15:41:30.275 -> Sending command: AT+CMGF=1
15:41:32.229 -> Response: 
15:41:32.229 -> OK

I also tried bunch of other commands to check sim status and everything works properly:
I had also tried 2 other sim cards and got the same issue. I'm assuming that something is wrong with my sim900 module. I tried ATZ to reset the module and also tried manually turning device off and on and nothing changed.
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

As per the datasheet, the command syntax is AT+CMGS=<number><CR><message><CTRL-Z>. So it looks like you are missing the CR character (\r) when you send the AT+CMGS command to the modem.
Your line should be:
SIM900.println("AT+CMGS=\"+381601xxxxxx\"\r");

Maybe you should also change the CTRL-Z print to:
SIM900.println("\x1a");


It didn't solve the problem. Same message again.

Can you post a full raw (hex) dump of the data going on the lines?
